# ClientHello Fails to negotiate TLS Version During handshake

Tags: ssl, jakarta-mail, tls1.2, handshake

I am trying to send mail using java mail. My mail server accepts only TLSv1.2. I tried to configure the TLSv1.2 in my client request. But, during TLS handshake my clientHello always using TLSv1. I tried to debug the handshake which is below,

```js
[22:10:45:099]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false|
[22:10:45:100]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1|
[22:10:45:100]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1|
[22:10:45:100]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1|
[22:10:45:100]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1|
[22:10:45:100]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1|
[22:10:45:100]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1|
[22:10:45:100]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1|
[22:10:45:100]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384|
[22:10:45:100]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384|
[22:10:45:100]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256|
[22:10:45:100]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384|
[22:10:45:100]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384|
[22:10:45:100]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256|
[22:10:45:100]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256|
[22:10:45:100]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256|
[22:10:45:100]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256|
[22:10:45:100]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256|
[22:10:45:100]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256|
[22:10:45:100]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256|
[22:10:45:100]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256|
[22:10:45:100]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256|
[22:10:45:100]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384|
[22:10:45:100]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256|
[22:10:45:101]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384|
[22:10:45:101]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384|
[22:10:45:101]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384|
[22:10:45:101]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384|
[22:10:45:101]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384|
[22:10:45:101]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384|
[22:10:45:101]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256|
[22:10:45:101]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256|
[22:10:45:101]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256|
[22:10:45:101]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256|
[22:10:45:101]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256|
[22:10:45:101]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256|
[22:10:45:101]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: %% No cached client session|
[22:10:45:102]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: *** ClientHello, TLSv1|
[22:10:45:102]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: RandomCookie:  |
[22:10:45:102]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: GMT: 1546533645 |
[22:10:45:102]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: bytes = { |
[22:10:45:102]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: 85|
[22:10:45:102]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: , |
[22:10:45:102]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: 83|
[22:10:45:102]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: , |
[22:10:45:102]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: 155|
[22:10:45:102]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: , |
[22:10:45:102]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: 171|
[22:10:45:102]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: , |
[22:10:45:102]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: 182|
[22:10:45:102]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: , |
[22:10:45:102]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: 72|
[22:10:45:102]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: , |
[22:10:45:102]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: 149|
[22:10:45:102]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: , |
[22:10:45:102]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: 172|
[22:10:45:102]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: , |
[22:10:45:102]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: 46|
[22:10:45:102]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: , |
[22:10:45:102]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: 116|
[22:10:45:102]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: , |
[22:10:45:102]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: 34|
[22:10:45:102]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: , |
[22:10:45:102]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: 18|
[22:10:45:102]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: , |
[22:10:45:102]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: 6|
[22:10:45:102]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: , |
[22:10:45:102]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: 97|
[22:10:45:102]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: , |
[22:10:45:102]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: 139|
[22:10:45:102]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: , |
[22:10:45:102]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: 142|
[22:10:45:102]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: , |
[22:10:45:102]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: 6|
[22:10:45:102]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: , |
[22:10:45:102]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: 223|
[22:10:45:102]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: , |
[22:10:45:102]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: 139|
[22:10:45:102]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: , |
[22:10:45:102]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: 14|
[22:10:45:102]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: , |
[22:10:45:102]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: 72|
[22:10:45:102]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: , |
[22:10:45:102]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: 51|
[22:10:45:102]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: , |
[22:10:45:102]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: 129|
[22:10:45:102]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: , |
[22:10:45:103]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: 210|
[22:10:45:103]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: , |
[22:10:45:103]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: 76|
[22:10:45:103]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: , |
[22:10:45:103]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: 177|
[22:10:45:103]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: , |
[22:10:45:103]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: 254|
[22:10:45:103]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: , |
[22:10:45:103]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: 144|
[22:10:45:103]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]:  }|
[22:10:45:103]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: Session ID:  |
[22:10:45:103]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: {}|
[22:10:45:103]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]|
[22:10:45:103]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: Compression Methods:  { |
[22:10:45:103]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: 0|
[22:10:45:103]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]:  }|
[22:10:45:103]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}|
[22:10:45:103]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]|
[22:10:45:103]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: Extension server_name, server_name: [type=host_name (0), value=mail.someserver.com]|
[22:10:45:103]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: ***|
[22:10:45:103]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: http-nio-8095-exec-3, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 175|
[22:10:45:227]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: http-nio-8095-exec-3, received EOFException: error|
[22:10:45:227]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: http-nio-8095-exec-3, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake|
[22:10:45:228]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: http-nio-8095-exec-3|
[22:10:45:228]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: , SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  |
[22:10:45:228]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: fatal, |
[22:10:45:228]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: description = handshake_failure|
[22:10:45:228]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: http-nio-8095-exec-3, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2|
[22:10:45:228]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[56]: http-nio-8095-exec-3, called closeSocket()|
[22:10:45:231]|[01-03-2019]|[SYSERR]|[INFO]|[56]: java.lang.Exception: Error in connecting to SMTP host.|
```

I made the below configurations in my client side to proceed the connection with TLSv1.2,

> -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
>
> -Dmail.smtp.ssl.protocols="TLSv1.2"
>
> -Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2

The Error thrown in my Mail server log is

> - SSL error 0x80090331 The client and server cannot communicate because they do not possess a common algorithm.

I couldn't figure out why the clientHello is always choosing TLSv1 instead of TLSv1.2 . Please help me with this.

```
public static void sendMail(JSONObject mailProps, JSONObject serverProps) throws Exception {
    boolean var2 = true;
    String mailPort;
    try {
        String mailServer = serverProps.getString("SERVER_NAME");
        mailPort = serverProps.getString("PORT");
        String mailAuthenUser = serverProps.has("USER_NAME") ? serverProps.getString("USER_NAME") : "";
        String mailAuthenPwd = serverProps.has("PASSWORD") ? serverProps.getString("PASSWORD") : "";
        String securityType = serverProps.has("CONNECTION_SECURITY") ? serverProps.getString("CONNECTION_SECURITY") : "";
        boolean isHtmlFormat = false;
        if (mailProps.has("ENABLE_HTML_FORMAT") && mailProps.getBoolean("ENABLE_HTML_FORMAT") || serverProps.has("ENABLE_HTML_FORMAT") && serverProps.getBoolean("ENABLE_HTML_FORMAT")) {
            isHtmlFormat = true;
        }

        String fromAddress = mailProps.has("FROM_MAIL_ID") ? mailProps.getString("FROM_MAIL_ID") : serverProps.getString("FROM_MAIL_ID");
        String toAddress = mailProps.has("TO_ADDRESSES") ? mailProps.getString("TO_ADDRESSES") : serverProps.getString("ADMIN_MAIL_ID");
        String subject = mailProps.getString("SUBJECT");
        String message = mailProps.getString("MESSAGE");
        Properties systemProps = System.getProperties();
        Properties properties = (Properties)systemProps.clone();
        properties.put("mail.smtp.host", mailServer);
        properties.put("mail.smtp.port", mailPort);
        properties.put("mail.smtp.sendpartial", "true");
        Session session = null;
        boolean authRequired = false;
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "false");
        if (mailAuthenUser != null && mailAuthenPwd != null && (!mailAuthenUser.equals("") || !mailAuthenPwd.equals(""))) {
            properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            authRequired = true;
        }

        if ("SSL".equalsIgnoreCase(securityType)) {
            properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", mailPort);
            properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
            properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
        } else if ("TLS".equalsIgnoreCase(securityType)) {
            properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
            properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.required", "true");
        }

        if (authRequired) {
            Authenticator auth = new MailAction.SMTPAuthenticator(mailAuthenUser, mailAuthenPwd);
            session = Session.getInstance(properties, auth);
        } else {
            session = Session.getInstance(properties);
        }

        session.setDebug(false);
        MimeMessage mess = new MimeMessage(session);
        if (toAddress != null) {
            String[] to = toAddress.split(",");
            InternetAddress[] toInternetAddress = new InternetAddress[to.length];

            for(int i = 0; i < to.length; ++i) {
                toInternetAddress[i] = new InternetAddress(to[i].trim());
            }

            mess.setRecipients(RecipientType.TO, toInternetAddress);
        }

        if (fromAddress != null && !fromAddress.equals("")) {
            mess.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromAddress));
        }

        String type;
        if (mailProps.has("PRIORITY")) {
            type = mailProps.get("PRIORITY").toString();
            if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("High") || type.equalsIgnoreCase("Low")) {
                mess.setHeader("Importance", type);
                mess.setHeader("X-Priority", type);
            }
        }

        type = isHtmlFormat ? "text/html;charset=UTF-8" : "text/plain;charset=UTF-8";
        mess.setContent(message, type);
        if (mailProps.has("CC_ADDRESS")) {
            String[] cc = (String[])((String[])mailProps.get("CC_ADDRESS"));
            InternetAddress[] ccInternetAddress = new InternetAddress[cc.length];

            for(int i = 0; i < cc.length; ++i) {
                ccInternetAddress[i] = new InternetAddress(cc[i].trim());
            }

            mess.setRecipients(RecipientType.CC, ccInternetAddress);
        }

        mess.setSentDate(new Date());
        mess.setSubject(subject, "UTF-8");
        Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(mess.getClass().getClassLoader());
        Transport.send(mess);
    } catch (Exception var29) {
        out.log(Level.INFO, " ", var29);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which version of Java you are using on client side? May be Java version does not support TLS1.2 or Java version does not support the protocols expected by the server.

Comment: java version "1.8.0_171" I hope this version supports TLSv1.2.  @Ajinkya

Comment: Can you provide more details about how client is making a request to server? Some other answers suggest that use these 2 properties while making SMTP connection mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true; mail.smtp.ssl.protocols=TLSv1.2;.
These are not jvm arguments, they are configuration properties for JavaMailSender.

Comment: I added my sendmail method @Ajinkya

Comment: Somewhere SSL Socket (Or SSL Socket factory) is getting created. Make sure that gets created with TLS1.2. Java 8 defaults TLS1.2 for TLS communication, so there is no reason that your Java 8 client will use TLSv1 unless explicitly specified so.

Answer (score 1):

This was the [hardcoded](https://github.com/javaee/javamail/commit/df5438b2592b6be31eccfd7f4e9aea08571c5e53) default in JavaMail pre-1.5.3, so upgrading should do the trick (keep in mind JavaMail has been superseded by [Jakarta Mail](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/mail/)).

As a workaround you can set the desired protocols as whitespace separated list (as suggested by Ajinkya)

```
properties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.protocols", "TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1");
```